# A server with the specified hostname could not be found

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, itunes

When I try to submit my app on the App Store through Xcode I got this error.

> A server with the specified hostname could not be found.

Is this temporary error at Apple or something to do with Xcode?

Is anyone else facing this problem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Keep Trying!**

I have had this a few times (including today), and each time, without changing anything, it has worked when I tried again.

Sometimes the 2nd time, other times 20 minutes later.

Comment: Yes, It was 5 minutes for me to get a success.

Comment: For me, it works fine on simulator but not on device! Will give it a try few minutes later!

Comment: Nailed it at 3.57 min

Comment: It worked for me but there should be a genuine reason for this issue.

Comment: What kind of answer is that? And it's accepted and upvoted 24 times?

Comment: This is a bad response.

Comment: Well, users really don't like when developers chose this sort of solutions

Comment: I faced the same error when I tried to install macOS Catalina from Software Update. It failed 4 times and then in started downloading.

Comment: Arguably not a good response, but worked for me. LoL

Comment: its really work, maybe its just issue on communication to the server update.
If it doesn't work, maybe another way is to change the DNS or if you have a dynamic IP connection you can reset your network

Comment: I've just rebooted my Mac and it problem disappeared

Answer (score 50):

In Xcode, select Target -> Capabilities, and check "Outgoing Connections (Client)" to enable App Sandbox.

Comment: i can't find this on xcode 11. can you please help me on this. thanks

Comment: @YogeshPatel the sandbox capability has been moved to the `.entitlements` file in Xcode 11. Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58833674/7003312

Comment: This really should be the correct answer.

Comment: This instantly worked for me!

Comment: The question is not about running an app that needs a network connection, the question is about submitting an app via Xcode. Big difference.

Comment: It baffles me that Xcode would not just say "outgoing connections not enabled" instead of blaming the server.

Answer (score 42):

It might be **DNS Pollution** issue, at least for my case (*in China*).

If you're also in China or some places that has DNS Pollution issue, you might solve this by modifying the DNS (to `8.8.8.8` as an example) for your Mac as well.

---

I got this error inner my iPad App & this happens randomly, it's such boring. Keep trying is not a good solution for me, though it might works somehow. Finally, I just changed my Wi-Fi DNS and no more error now. Steps:

1. Your device, Settings/Wi-Fi
2. Choose connected Wi-Fi pot
3. Press DHCP/DNS
4. Set to `8.8.8.8`

Comment: Thanks! this fixed my issue... but the same url caused this error in my app worked fine in Safari. Any idea?

Comment: @ztwei the app & Safari are in same device? not sure about ur issue, it depends, and also, DNS pollution triggers randomly as well, not always.

Comment: ya the same device ... and the url works in Safari no matter how the DNS gets modified.

Comment: @ztwei not sure about it, but Safari might have some tech handles this well, i just search w/ key words "safari, dns" in Google, the first record said _"... Apple added a significant new feature to Safari in version 5.0.1. It hasn't garnered much attention and you may not have heard about it. It's called DNS prefetching, and its purpose is to speed up the loading of Web pages."_ i'm not sure about it, but seems it indeed has some techs inner the app. If u'r also an iOS developer, u should know that we can also support VPN inner app.

Answer (score 18):

For me it was an issue with enabling Outgoing connections in Capabilities tab.

[image]

Comment: The question is not about running an app that needs a network connection, the question is about submitting an app via Xcode. Big difference.

Answer (score 15):

If the problem occured in a MacOS project, as @nstein commented in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47219898/1404324) just go to your `Target`'s `Signing & Capabilities` and allow `Incoming` and `Outgoing` network options.

Comment: What about for an iOS project?

Comment: absolutely no idea @Aspen

Comment: It's under the "App Sandbox" capability

Comment: The question is not about running an app that needs a network connection, the question is about submitting an app via Xcode. Big difference.

Answer (score 13):

I received `A server with the specified hostname could not be found.`. I figured out my MacOS app had turned on App Sandboxing. The easiest way to avoid problem is to turn off Sandbox.

Comment: Or keep the App Sandboxing, which is required for the Mac App Store and, simply allow Incoming (Server) and Outgoing (Client) Connections.

Answer (score 12):

That fixed the problem for me, when trying to upgrade to El Capitan:

```
sudo softwareupdate --clear-catalog
```

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem, it turned out to be VPN related. If you are testing on a device against a corporate network, chances are your Mac has proper VPN set up, but your phone does not. **Connect phone to the corporate VPN** for your apps deployed to device to see corporate servers.

Comment: Hi I am connected to corporate vpn with same credentials and its working fine on simulator but on device even with usb wifi sharing the same error...

Comment: This was the issue- Saved my time

Answer (score 3):

I restarted my MacBook Pro and then I build again, the error was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I got this message when the device has mobile data turned on and no wifi connection, but the internet is not properly connected.

Try to connect to a wifi network with an internet connection or turning off the mobile data.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. Actually i face it often. Following three steps work for me always

1. Change DNS to 8.8.8.8 and 4.2.2.2
2. Open net.properties and change "# https.proxyPort=443" to "https.proxyPort=80". You can find net.properties here /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/java/lib/net.properties
3. Open Application Loader->Preferences->Advanced and uncheck Signiant and Aspera. Make sure DAV is checked.

Thants all. Now you can submit app using both application loader and Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

A server with the specified hostname could not be found.

I faced the same problem, In my case it was because of-

1. Server was not configured properly.
2. Server subscription has been expired

Contacting to server hosting company resolve my problem.

I think this is not temporary error at apple or something to do with Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your internet connection.. go to safari and check by searching something on google(dont try google.com only.. because it can be cached). If it is working fine, then try now in your app. It must work. This is fired while not having proper internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Just to share my experience

It was caused by the **Sharing > Internet Sharing** inside System **Preferences**

I was testing and created **NAT64 Network** unchecking it solved my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when we changed from one domain to another for API service.

Restarting the network router/modem fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message when "/" from my URL is missing . Hope this help someone.

ex: actual URL is "https://www.myweb.com/login" .My URL which "https://www.myweb.comlogin"  caused this error

Answer (score 0):

Just **restart** your network router device.

> Obs. If it is already has automatic DNS settings.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was occurring while validating build before upload. Just before that we had server issue.
I tried restart Mac, quit Xcode multiple times, doesn't work. Also try to sign in from organiser but connection was not getting established.

Later from account, I tried sign in and thats done and then validate and build gets uploaded.

For xcode 12.4.1

Answer (score 0):

This is network error, this issue fixed for me with turn off/on my network and run again...

This is just my experience and it's not always true, given that every situation is different and can be fixed in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

I know my reply is late but it is better than not replying

Most likely there is a problem with the Internet
But the fastest way after long attempts

***run vpn***

Answer (score -1):

Turn off the push notification. Then,**Restart your XCode** and Turn back ON the Push Notification. It works for me.