# dns pollution - a server with the specified hostname could not be found

Tags: ios, dns

I had the same issue with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279491/a-server-with-the-specified-hostname-could-not-be-found) about iOS app with server error.

One of my iOS app user was located in China (running on iPad mini/ iOS 8),
the [answer about DNS Pollution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22551135/4062660) solved my issue.

My wondering is that my app got this error when sent an url:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003
>
> "a server with the specified hostname could not be found"

but got the correct data in Safari with the same url.

I suppose the response should be no difference(either data or error) on any app sending the same request ... if this issue is caused by DNS server?

If not... what would be the case and what can I do to prevent it from my app?

Answer (score 0):

It should be a DNS issue. If you are using a subdomain, you need to add a new A record with your domain provider to redirect it to your server.

Hope that helps.