# Command Line Tools update fails when contacting server

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, xcode-command-line-tools

Using Software Update I see an update is available for "Command Line Tools (maxOS Mojave version 10.14) for Xcode 1." When I click to update and agree to the terms and conditions I get the following error:

```
A server with the specified hostname could not be found.
```

Attempted fixes:

- turning off my vpn which uses it's own DNS system (internet does work when I turn this off)
- updating my DNS when the vpn is off (I've tried 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4)

I tried many of this fixes listed for a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279491/a-server-with-the-specified-hostname-could-not-be-found) including:

- just waiting awhile
- `sudo softwareupdate --clear-catalog`
- restarting my computer
- restarting my router

What else can I try here? Is there anything I should check is turned on / off?