# App Sandbox capability missing in Xcode project

Tags: xcode, appstore-sandbox, xcodeproj

According to this guide, there should be an `App Sandbox` capability in the project file:

[image]

However, for some reason my app project does not have any `App Sandbox` capability that I can turn on:

[image]

Why is it missing, and how can I get it there?

Comment: Appstore-Sandbox is for Mac OS X Apps. In iOS the sandbox is always turned on and can't be configured. What are you trying to configure?

Answer (score 23):

First of all, you should open the `***.entitlements` file. In this file, add a Key named `App Sandbox` and changed Value to `YES`.

After completing the above steps, click `command + b` then go back to `Signing & Capabilities`, the `App Sandbox` will appear.

Comment: this answer works but it will take a 5 -10 minutes before it appears

Comment: I can't find this file when the project was created, what can I do?

Comment: It doesn't appear tho

Answer (score 5):

### **Add missing App Sandbox capability**

(Straightforward to do but a pain to remember.)

1. If your project lacks a `.entitlements` file, create a new one:

- Menu: `View` > `Navigators` > `Project`
- Select the root level (project icon) of your project
- Menu: `File` > `New` > `File...`
- Use the `Property List` template
- Name the file after your project. Example: `MYPROJECT.entitlements`.

2. Edit the file:

- Select the file in the Project navigator sidebar.
- Add a new row (via the `(+)` symbol, just as you would for a `.plist` file.)

  key: `App Sandbox`    type: `Boolean`    value: `YES`

  This is the same as editing the source code (file contents) to be:

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
      <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
      <true/>
  </dict>
  </plist>
  ```

3. Register this new file in the built target settings for your project.

- Menu: `View` > `Navigators` > `Project`
- Select the root level (project icon) of your project
- In the `project and targets list` (left sidebar within the editor), select the target under **TARGETS** (not the Project)
- In the editor area, select the `Build Settings` tab
- Select `All` (show all build settings), not `Basic`
- In the list, find `CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS`
- Set its value to the location of the `.entitlements` file. If you created it at the root level of the project, this is just the filename, otherwise the relative folder path.

  Example: `butterflies.entitlements`
  Example: `butterflies/butterflies.entitlements`

I recommend then doing a `Clean Build Folder`, select a suitable build platform and doing a Product `Build` or `Run`.

Caveat: `App Sandbox` can be missing for other reasons but this is the most common one I come across.

Answer (score 4):

If your Apple provisioning profile is missing the **App Sandbox** entitlement then it won't show up in xcode.

FYI - you can add manually to entitlement file, however it wont let you build unless described in your provisioning profile. Same goes for ditribution as well.

To Add entitlement > Open *.entitlements file as source code > add the following code.

`<key>App Sandbox</key> <true/>`

You can regenerate the provisioning profile with the desired capabilities, if you are the admin/team agent of the Apple store project.

hope this helps.